# override inherited event with generic type

Tags: c#

I have a simple class that should fire an event and pass in some data of type object because I don't know the type of data at this point. So my example class is

```
class Foo
{
    public virtual event Action<object> OnStateUpdated;

    public void Add(Button button)
    {
        button.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    protected virtual void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnStateUpdated("This will return data of type object");
    }
}
```

You can add a button and when clicking it you will receive a string of type object. I would like to be able to pass in a generic type so that I know the type when the event gets fired. I inherit from this class and create a generic child.

```
class Bar<ValueType> : Foo
{
    public override event Action<ValueType> OnStateUpdated;

    protected override void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnStateUpdated(default); // this returns data of type ValueType
    }
}
```

This class should override the event and pass in the correct type.

- If the user creates an instance of `Foo` and listens for `OnStateUpdated` he should get data of type `object`.
- If he creates an instance of `Bar<string>` and listens for `OnStateUpdated` he should get data of type `string`.

Unfortunately I can't override the event because it has to be of type object. So my current solution is to make us of the `new` keyword. Instead of overriding the event and click handler I use `new` to hide the parent.

For the sake of completeness this would be the updated working code

```
class Foo
{
    public event Action<object> OnStateUpdated;

    // Add method

    private void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnStateUpdated("This will return data of type object");
    }
}

class Bar<ValueType> : Foo
{
    public new event Action<ValueType> OnStateUpdated;

    private new void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnStateUpdated(default); // this returns data of type ValueType
    }
}
```

So my question is: This seems to be a valid solution, are there any better ones? `Bar` inherits the `Add` method from `Foo`, will the button always use the correct event handler?

Comment: Why not just make Foo generic itself? you could still use it to return any type by making an instance of Foo<Type>, then you don't even need the Bar class, since it does the same thing

Comment: `class Foo<TEventAction>{ ... event Action<TEventAction> OnStateUpdated`? When overriding a member, you must match its type as you have found out.

Comment: @ GlennvanAcker sorry, I can't because `Foo` should not be generic. That's why I created a child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a generic interface with the event and implement it in both classes

```cs
public interface IFoo<out T>
{
    event Action<T> OnStateUpdated;
}
```

Classes implementation

```cs
class Foo : IFoo<object>
{
    public event Action<object> OnStateUpdated;

    // Add method

    private void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnStateUpdated?.Invoke("This will return data of type object");
    }
}

class Bar: IFoo<ValueType>
{
    public event Action<ValueType> OnStateUpdated;

    private new void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnStateUpdated?.Invoke(default); // this returns data of type ValueType
    }
}
```

You also have to properly invoke the `Action`, using [thread safe invocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#thread-safe-delegate-invocation) with `?.` operator